# where does Silverlight app's executable/assembly/whatever actually get installed on my hard drive? 

Tags: silverlight, windows-7

I installed a silverlight app on Windows 7, it put up a shortcut on the desktop and it works fine. E.g. works fine without internet connection.

What worries me is, it's unclear where exactly that app now is on my machine. I examined this desktop shortcut and it says "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" [Random Integer].[Url Name associated with the app]

Yeah, great. So where is the executable/assembly/whatever that will actually get loaded by sllauncher.exe?

ETA: ok, this guy http://www.qa.com/about-qa/blogs/2011/september/where-is-an-out-of-browser-silverlight-xap-stored/ claims that Silverlight files have extension XAP and are saved in C:\Users\Username\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser . Not sure how true that is in general, but this is not the case for the specific case of my machine. AFAICT my OutOfBrowser folder is very small, contains no XAP files, no hidden files etc.

Answer (score 2):

ok, so it turns out that the XAP package was not installed in C:\Users\Username\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser as suggested by the friendly Silverlight trainer-and-blogger-too. No, it was installed in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser .

"because we are not satisfied until you are not satisfied" http://www.despair.com/cudi.html must be the Windows team's new motto.